# Tableview sliding up after scroll to row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hey guys I need your help please, when I reload a tableview and call the scroll to row function for the bottom row (array.length - 1) as index path, it scrolls to it, then it scrolls one row up. I have made a cool chat part to my app, and it is simple, I have a function that grabs messages, and for some reason on my iPhone simulator, it does this weird scrolling back up motion. Basically I was hoping one of you guys could help me find out why it is doing that. It is some simple code.

main function:

```
  func grabMessages () {
    if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        if let theirId = theirUid {
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            ref.child("users").child(uid).child("chats").child(theirId).child("messages").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
                var reloadi = false
                if let values = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    for (_, one) in values {
                        if let whoSent = one["sender"] as? String, let messagl = one["message"] as? String, let timerl = one["timeStamp"] as? Int, let keyer = one["key"] as? String {
                            let newMess = Message()
                            print("googd")
                            newMess.key = keyer
                            newMess.timeStamp = timerl
                            newMess.messager = messagl
                            newMess.sender = whoSent

                                   if self.messages.contains( where: { $0.key == newMess.key } )  {
                                   } else {

                                self.messages.append(newMess)
                                    if self.messages.count != 0 {
                                        self.messages.sort { $1.timeStamp > $0.timeStamp }
                                   reloadi = true
                                    }
                                    if newMess.sender == theirId {
                            let update = ["unseen" : "iViewed"]
                            ref.child("users").child(theirId).child("chats").child(uid).updateChildValues(update)


                                    }

                            }


                    }

                    if reloadi == true {
                        reloadi = false
                         DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tablerView.reloadData()
                     let indexPat = IndexPath(row: 0, section: self.messages.count - 1)
                        self.tablerView.isHidden = false
                    self.tablerView.scrollToRow(at: indexPat, at: .bottom, animated: false)
                    }

                    }



                }
            }, withCancel: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I will say in my viewdidload I set the frame of the tableview, which is just a cgrect and same size across all platform, fixed width and height. And on my own iPhone it runs and works fine, only on simulator iPhones did it do this.

Here is a screen shot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBwrV.jpg

So if you can see, it shows other section below it, but it is scrolled to the one above it. So it originally scrolls to it, then scrolls back up one section.

some other stuff 
numb of sections = messages.count

number of rows in section = 1